# jQuery validation depends rule not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working on a signup form and using jQuery validation to check the form. I want to validate the day of birth so that they can't select for example day 31 for february.
My code is:

```
birthday:  {
             required: true,
             min: 1,
             max: {
             depends: function(element) {
              switch (parseInt($('#birthmonth').val())){
                     case 2:
                            maxday = 29;
                            break;
                     case 4:
                     case 6:
                     case 9:
                     case 11:
                            maxday = 30;
                            break;
                     default:
                            maxday = 31;                                
                 }                                                
              return maxday;
                 }}
            },
```

The `switch` is working and the function returns the correct value for each month, but the validation still shows invalid selection even when I select any month then day 7. I tried to convert back the return value to string, but it's still not working.

Comment: It would be nice if you would have included a full `.validate()` call and enough markup for a concise demo... it reduces the amount of work required to answer as well as helping future readers understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This would work out a little better for you inside of a custom method.  Create your new rule by using [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            birthday: {
                required: true,
                min: 1,
                mymax: ['#birthmonth']
            }
        }
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('mymax', function (value, element, params) {
        switch (parseInt($(params[0]).val())) {
            case 2:
                maxday = 29;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                maxday = 30;
                break;
            default:
                maxday = 31;
        }
        params[1] = maxday;  // simply used for populating message at {1}
        return parseInt(value) <= maxday;
    }, "Please enter a value less than or equal to {1}");

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Uv8Y/**